# Difference of convex functions

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

Let $f_1(x)$, $f_2(x)$, and $f_3(x)$ all be decreasing and convex functions, $x\geq 0$. Furthermore, let's assume $1\geq f_1(x)> f_2(x)> f_3(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\geq 0$. Let $g(x)=\frac{f_1(x)-f_2(x)}{f_1(x)-f_3(x)}$. If we know the difference between $f_1(x)-f_2(x)$ and $f_1(x)-f_3(x)$ is decreasing in $x$, e.g. $\left(f_1(x+\epsilon)-f_3(x+\epsilon)\right)-\left(f_1(x+\epsilon)-f_2(x+\epsilon)\right)\leq \left(f_1(x)-f_3(x)\right)-\left(f_1(x)-f_2(x)\right)$ for $\epsilon>0$, how does $g(x)$ behave with regard to $x$? What are some sufficient conditions that would make $g(x)$ monotonically increasing or decreasing in $x$?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have enough reputation to comment so I'm using the answer section. Have you tried solving it for some specific decreasing convex functions? To start, I would recommend trying out something simple like $f_i(x)=\frac{1}{i+x}$, $i \in (1,2,3)$ which satisfy all the conditions you listed. You can then write $g(x)=\frac{x+3}{2x+4}$. Take f.o.c w.r.t. $x$, you can see $\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x}=-\frac{1}{2(x+2)^2}<0$. Personally, I do not see how you can answer the question without actually knowing $f_i(x)$.

Comment: Thanks, I did try a few simple decreasing convex functions. All of them ended up with $\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x}\leq 0$. I am not able to come up with examples where $g(x)$ is increasing in $x$. I've also been wondering if $g(x)$ first decreases in $x$, then increases in $x$, since intuitively, as the difference of interest decreases, $g(x)$ approaches $1$ for some large $x$. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have anymore information on how $f_1(x)-f_2(x)$ compares to $f_1(x)-f_3(x)$?